# Tablesorter bug cloning table row with jquery

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to wrap my head around why rows are being duplicated once removed only when the tablesorter function is being used.  Here is the page in question:

http://www.ffxiv-gathering.com/40.php

To duplicate the bug do the following:

1. Click any row on the Unspoiled tab
2. Go to the Watching tab
3. Click the row to remove it
4. Go to the Unspoiled tab and click a row...then click another
5. Go to Watching tab

You can see the first row that was initially clicked was duplicated.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why.  Removing the tablesorter function fixes the problem...however, I would like that to remain as it sorts the table by status (and thus moves the current and upcoming nodes to the top).

Here is the jquery running this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var items = [];

$("#myTable-unspoiled >tbody >tr").on("click", function() {
    var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone().addClass("remove");

    items.push(newTr);
    newTr.appendTo($("#myTable-watching"));

    $(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    var rowCount = $('#myTable-watching >tbody >tr').length;
    $('#counter').html(rowCount);
    });

    var rowCount = $('#myTable-watching >tbody >tr').length;
    $('#counter').html(rowCount);

    $("#myTable-watching").tablesorter({ 
    // sort status column, then item; ascending
    sortList: [[6,0],[0,0]]
    });
});
});
```

Removing this fixes the problem but prevents me from sorting:

```
$("#myTable-watching").tablesorter({ 
    // sort status column, then item; ascending
    sortList: [[6,0],[0,0]]
});
```

Here is a page without the tablesorter plugin.

http://www.ffxiv-gathering.com/40-test.php

To see my issue...click a colored row, then a white row, then another colored row and view the Watching tab.

Comment: Have you tried `$("#myTable-watching").tablesorter({ ... });` out of the `click` handler?

Answer (score 0):

When you add and/or remove rows from the table, make sure you trigger an "update" instead of reinitializing tablesorter...

```
newTr.appendTo($("#myTable-watching"));
$("#myTable-watching").trigger("update");
```

and

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    var $table = $(this).closest('table');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $table.trigger('update');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully!

If I want to add rows from another table will I need to create another function with the other table id or is there a way to call more than one table id with a click function?

Comment: I answered my own question.  Thanks again for your help.